# Can rush API have a dynamic pickup destination?

Tags: uber-api

When I was setting up an Uber rush API account it asked me for an address where items will be picked up.

So if I want to deliver items do I need to have a static address or can it be dynamic?

If you see this documentation: https://developer.uber.com/docs/deliveries/references/api/v1/deliveries-post
Under pickup['location'] there's an address section, therefore I'm thinking I can have the pickup location be dynamic and not static, but why would the sign up process ask for an address where items will be picked up?

Anyone know whether I can have items picked up anywhere?

Comment: Can you add a link to the Uber rush API documentation you have read?

Answer (score 0):

The pickup address can be dynamic for deliveries made through the API.

The pickup address specified during the signup process is used as the default address when using the small business merchant dashboard under https://rush.uber.com